# selenium can not find html element on firefox

Tags: python, firefox, selenium, rc

I try to verifiy in selenium RC with python:
sel.is_element_present("//div[@id='USER_PHOTOS']/div[1]/span[1]/img)
but looks like can not get it right.
and tried this:
sel.is_element_present("//div[@id='USER_PHOTOS'])
it works.
did anyone why it can't find the sub tag here:

```
<div class="bx01 deals swirllinks">
<div id="USER_PHOTOS" class="bx01">
<div class="ug_photos">
    <span class="u_/LocationPhotos-g294212-d1234659-Fairmont_Beijing-Beijing.html#41195738 fkASDF fkLnk" onclick="setPID(3901); return ta.call('ta.overlays.Factory.photosLB', event, this);">
        <img class="ug_photo" alt="coffee machine" src="http://ccm.ddcdn.com/ext/photo-l/02/5d/7c/f6/coffee-machine.jpg"/>
    </span>
    <span class="u_/LocationPhotos-g294212-d1234659-Fairmont_Beijing-Beijing.html#41195739 fkASDF fkLnk" onclick="setPID(3901); return ta.call('ta.overlays.Factory.photosLB', event, this);">
        <img class="ug_photo" alt="bathroom" src="http://ccm.ddcdn.com/ext/photo-l/02/5d/7c/f7/bathroom.jpg"/>
    </span>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your xpath - //div[@id='USER_PHOTOS']**/div[1]**/span[1]/img , selenium will look for a div **under** div id = USER_PHOTOS. Your span **doesn't come under** "USER_PHOTOS" its under the `<div class="ug_photos">`

You should use `//div[@class='ug_photos']//span[1]/img`